# Interpolation of $H_{mix}$

Tags: thermodynamics

Given two points $(P,T, H_{mix})$, how can I interpolate $H_{mix}$ between them?

[image: Two Point Interpolation]

In other words, if I had two points $(H_1, P_1, T_1)$ and $(H_2, P_2, T_2)$, where $H_{mix}$ is the enthalpy of mixing, $P$ is the pressure and $T$ is the temperature, how would I interpolate between them? I started with the differential
$$dH = \frac{\partial H_{mix}}{\partial P}dP + \frac{\partial H_{mix}}{\partial T}dT$$
To interpolate, I would need to integrate this from $P_1,T_1$ to $P_2,T_2$.
$$\Delta H_{mix} =\int _{P_{1}}^{P_{2}}\left(\frac{\partial H_{mix}}{\partial P}\right)_{T} dP+\int _{T_{1}}^{T_{2}}\left(\frac{\partial H_{mix}}{\partial T}\right)_{P} dT$$
This simplifies to
$$\Delta H_{mix} =\int _{P_{1}}^{P_{2}} -C_{P} \mu _{J} dP+\int _{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} C_{P} dT=-C_P\mu_J(P_2-P_1)
+C_P(T_2-T_1)$$
$C_P$ is the isobaric heat capacity and $\mu_J$ is the Joule-Thomson Coefficient. However, I do not know if this is correct or what my next step would be.

Comment: Are the pressures outside the range of ideal gas behavior?

Comment: @ChetMiller They are in the range of $0-10 GPa$

Comment: OK.  Is the mixture of constant composition?  If so, you are going to need to know (or estimate) the PVT behavior of the gas.  Please also be aware that Cp is a function of pressure as well as temperature (beyond the ideal gas recon).  You, at least, are going to need to know Cp vs T in the limit of ideal gas pressure range.

Comment: The mixture is not constant composition. It is $x:64$ O2:H2O, where $x$ can be anything from $25$ to $35$.

Comment: Is it constant between T1,P1 and T2,P2?

Comment: Yes, the composition is constant between $T_1, P_1$ and $T_2, P_2$ (i.e., does not undergo any phase changes), but I would like to see how the interpolation differs for different compositions (i.e., different ratios of O2 to H2O)

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the heat of mixing of a gas mixture at, say, T1,P1?

Comment: @ChetMiller I assume you mean the enthalpy of mixing? If so, then yes, I have already calculated $H_1$ and $H_2$ for $T_1,P_1$ and $T_2, P_2$. My problem is regarding how to interpolate between these two $H_{mix}$ values.

Comment: Why not calculate it for other points the same way you did it for points 1 and 2?

Comment: @ChetMiller It is extremely numerically expensive to do so (i.e., my simulations have an extremely long computing time, in part because of the myriad of calculations required to compute $H_{mix}$ for the system in question)

Comment: How is enthalpy measured, by heat content raising or lowering temperature. If pressure is constant then heat is enthalpy and if volume is constant then internal energy. And if temperature is constant then heat is converted into work. So how your homework question measure heat.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but if you want to interpolate you don't need heat capacities etc, just use the interpolation formula. In your case you need a double interpolation, which means you need *four* tabulated enthalpies, at two temperatures and two pressures that hopefully bracket the temperature and pressure of your calculation. The double interpolation is schematically shown below on the right.

[image]

In yous case $x$ is $T$, $y$ is $P$ and $f$ is $H$. The double interpolation formula is

$$
   H(T,P) = (1-a)(1-b) H_{11}
          + b(1-a) H_{12}
          + a(1-b) H_{21}
          + a b H_{22}
$$
with $H_{ij}=H(T_i,P_j)$ and
$$
   a = \frac{T-T_1}{T_2-T_1},\quad
   b = \frac{P-P_1}{P_2-P_1},\quad
$$
For this to work you need *four* points, not just two.

(The figure is from [this book](https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/fundamentals-of-chemical-engineering-thermodynamics/P200000009315/9780132693066))

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a perhaps naive question: as I have 3 variables $(x,y,f(x,y))$, would the interpolation not result in a 3D plot?

Comment: Well, the interpolation itself will not yield a plot, you will get the enthalpy at point $(T,P)$. Maybe I don't understand your question?

Comment: Right, I am referring to the fact that I have three variables $(P,T,H)$, so I would need to plot everything in 3D, correct?

Comment: @DarkRunner If $H$ is a function of $T$ and $P$, you have a 2D surface. You don't have a triplet of points (i.e., $(P,\,T,\,H)$), you have a function $H(P,\,T)$.

Comment: @KyleKanos I see, thank you.

Comment: @DarkRunner Can you share your data points (table or graph) and the $T$ & $P$ where you want the enthalpy?

Comment: @Themis Sure. I have only two data points (it is very numerically expensive to calculate each): $(P,T,H(P,T)): (2.6, 350, -1.19) \& (10.4, 350, 5.6)$

Comment: @DarkRunner Since you only have two points and both are at the same $T=350$, you can only interpolate for the enthalpy at $T=350$ with $2.6\leq P\leq 5.6$. You can also extrapolate outside this pressure range but accuracy will suffer. What is the $T$ and $P$ where you want to interpolate?

Comment: @Themis I see your point. I'd like to interpolate from slightly below room temperature to slightly above my calculated points, from about $285 K\leq T\leq 365 K$. As for $P$, I would like to interpolate for $2.6\leq P \leq 5.6$.

Comment: You need two temperatures to estimate the effect of temperature on Hmix. With only  one temperature you have to assume that temperature has no effect, then interpolate for pressure (the derivative $\partial H/\partial T$ is basically the parameter $a$ in my formula and takes two temperatures to evaluate). However, the effect of temperature on $H_\text{mix}$ is usually stronger that of pressure, so you have to make a judgement.

Comment: @Themis I see. Does that mean my interpolation formula will simply be $b=\frac{P-P_1}{P_2-P_1}$?

Comment: Yes, provided that your temperature is 350. This amounts to drawing a straight line between the two black circles in tour picture. By the way, in your picture your $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the same and equal to 320.

Comment: I see, it was meant to be a representative picture, but I'll edit it shortly. Basically then, I'm simply drawing the line that connects the two points? I had hoped that I could hopefully extrapolate to other temperatures, but I was not aware that I needed at least another $T_2$ to do so. Is there any other way I can extrapolate across the desired temperature range? I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I am afraid thre is no way to extrapolate to other temperatures from a single temperature: you need two  so that you can estimate the magnitude of $\partial H/\partial T$.