# Holding things constant in Statistical Physics for differentiation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differentiation

I just want to know if the following is correct:
If one wants to verify e.g. the Maxwell relation for the ideal gas $$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N}=- \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} $$ one isn‘t allowed to use $pV=Nk_BT$ and $E=\frac{3}{2}Nk_BT$ which makes sense because the first expression is derived by holding $E$ constant and the second by holding $V$ constant and hence we are taking derivatives in different charts of our manifold. Therefore we need to have $T(V,S,N)$ and $p(V,S,N)$ as functions of $S,V$ and $N$.
However if we don‘t take derivatives we can insert the relations in each other and get e.g. $E=\frac{3}{2}pV $ even if they were derived by keeping different constant. Is that correct?

Comment: Sure, except that the total energy is $N\frac{3}{2}k_BT$ (since $\frac{3}{2}k_BT$ is the average energy *per particle* for a monatomic ideal gas).

Comment: @march ah yes of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know if the following is correct:
> If one wants to verify e.g. the Maxwell relation for the ideal gas $$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N}=- \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N} $$ one isn‘t allowed to use $pV=Nk_BT$ and $E=\frac{3}{2}k_BT$ which makes sense because the first expression is derived by holding $E$ constant and the second by holding $V$ constant and hence we are taking derivatives in different charts of our manifold. Therefore we need to have $T(V,S,N)$ and $p(V,S,N)$ as functions of $S,V$ and $N$.
> However if we don‘t take derivatives we can insert the relations in each other and get e.g. $E=\frac{3}{2}\frac{pV}{N} $ even if they were derived by keeping different constant. Is that correct?

You don't need to use any specific functional form for E. You just use the first law of thermodynamics ($dE = TdS - pdV$) and use the fact that partial derivatives commute.

It is a basic fact of multivariable calculus that partial derivative commute:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial V\partial S} = \frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial S\partial V}
$$

---

The LHS of the above can be written as:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial V\partial S} = \frac{\partial }{\partial V}\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\;,
$$
and then using the first law of thermodynamics $dE = TdS - pdV$ we see that $\partial E/\partial S$ is just $T$ and so we can write:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial V\partial S} = \frac{\partial }{\partial V}\frac{\partial E}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \tag{1}
$$

---

The RHS of the above can be written as:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial S\partial V} = \frac{\partial }{\partial S}\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\;,
$$
and then using the first law of thermodynamics $dE = TdS - pdV$ we see that $\partial E/\partial V$ is just $-p$ and so we can write:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial S\partial V} = \frac{\partial }{\partial S}\frac{\partial E}{\partial V} = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial S} \tag{2}
$$

---

Equating the far right-hand sides of Eq. (1) and Eq. (2) above shows that:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}
$$

We have not performed any Legendre transformation or otherwise tried to replace variables, so the function $T=T(S,V)$ and the function $p(S,V)$. Therefore, if we want to be very explicit we can also write this as:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S
=-\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)_V
$$

---

Everything works through exactly the same if we allow for variable particle number $N$, in which case $dE = TdS - pdV + \mu dN$. We never touch N, except to hold it constant in all the manipulation, so we can also write our result as:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N}
=-\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}
$$

Comment: Partial derivative dont always commute, Partial derivatives commute given the differential is exact

Comment: The differential is exact, my friend.

Comment: Just clarifying for OP since your statement generalises it

Comment: It's not clear to me that your comment clarifies for OP or obfuscates for OP... I guess OP can weigh in on that.

Comment: Thank you, but the derivation of this is clear. I just found it a little bit confusing that we can use the formulas, that we derived in a system where we changed e.g. the volume, for a system where we now change the energy of the system.

Comment: Hi @hft, I ask a similar question on thermodynamic differentials, but I have not received a satisfactory response yet. It would be great if you could take a look: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746178/interpolation-of-h-mix

Comment: @jensenpaull Wait, what? Partial derivatives always commute if they are continuous. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying...

Comment: Sorry i meant in the context of deriving the maxwell relations, for an exact differential $$dU=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V} dS + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S} dV$$  ,  To equate $T = \frac{\partial U}{\partial s}_{v}, and -p = \frac{\partial U}{\partial s}_{s}$ Requires you to assume dU is exact ( matching coefficients) Such that when you differentiate with respect to the other variable, the partial derivative commute since the original functions are what you claim them to be.  i shouldve said "These " partial derivatives,

Comment: @DarkRunner I will take a look. But not sure I can answer right away, if at all provide a satisfactory answer. Looks more complicated...

Comment: Sure, thank you for considering it.